# Finding if my function inside an rscript file is been called by either an rmarkdown or an rscript

Tags: r, r-markdown, rscript

I have a function in an Rscript (this is inside an r-package of my own) that is been called either by an `.R`(Rscript) file or an `.Rmd`(rmarkdown).
I need to create an if statement inside this function to do things depending if the function is called by either the Rscript or the Rmarkdown.

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit on why you need that? It seems highly uncommon to make this distiction within a function. Usually the better way would be to have two functions, one for `.Rmd` and one for `.R`. If the two functions have a lot of common functionality, you can extract that to a third function that is called by the other two. Or maybe a function argument that makes the distiction.

Comment: I am using some r-packages that do not work well with r-markdowns therefore I disable some functionalities from my own function in order for it to work with both .R and .Rmd. I would like to enable this functionalities when a regular .R file is calling the function otherwise keep them disable. At this point the function is embedded in many other functions so I thought the best solution would be to turn those specific functionalities on/off depending on the file that is calling the function.
But now that you mention this I will give it some thought and perhaps restructure a few things around.

Comment: If you do have control over the Rmarkdown files themselves, easiest is to use a function argument such as `from_markdown=TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the following solves the issue

Getting the file path that also includes filename and extension:

```
file_type <- try(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path, silent = T)
```

Getting the file extension.

```
file_type <- tools::file_ext(file_type)
```

Then iff `file_type = 'R'` the functionalities are turned on and for any other cases they are off.

```
if(file_type == 'R'){
    ...
  }
```

In this specific case I only care that the extension is a '.R' and don't want to risk using the functionalities with anything else.
For example if you are running the function in the console then `file_type = ''` and the functionalities will be off.